# Why does using an Object Initializer keep an object alive?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, weak-references, object-initializers

I recently came across this [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1686438/222434) and tweaked it for my scenario which follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication18
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Manager mgr = new Manager();
            var obj = new byte[1024];

            var refContainer = new RefContainer();
            refContainer.Target = obj;

            obj = null;

            mgr["abc"] = refContainer.Target;

            GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
            Console.WriteLine(mgr["abc"] != null); // true (still ref'd by "obj")

            refContainer = null;

            GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
            Console.WriteLine(mgr["abc"] != null); // false (no remaining refs)           
        }
    }

    class RefContainer
    {
        public object Target { get; set; }
    }

    class Manager
    {
        Dictionary<string, WeakReference> refs =
        new Dictionary<string, WeakReference>();
        public object this[string key]
        {
            get
            {
                WeakReference wr;
                if (refs.TryGetValue(key, out wr))
                {
                    if (wr.IsAlive)
                        return wr.Target;
                    refs.Remove(key);
                }
                return null;
            }
            set
            {
                refs[key] = new WeakReference(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running this program gives the following expected result:

```
True
False
Press any key to continue . . .
```

However change this:

```
var refContainer = new RefContainer();
refContainer.Target = obj;
```

To this (using Object Initializer syntax):

```
var refContainer = new RefContainer() { Target = obj };
```

Gives the following output:

```
True
True
Press any key to continue . . .
```

What's going on here? Why would lifetime of the reference be different just because of using Object Initializer?

Comment: Hmm... it prints "False, False" for me. I can't get it to print True at all. Are you running this under the debugger? Debug or Release build?

Comment: @JonSkeet-Running under the debugger, yes.

Comment: I tryed it with unit tests, same results as posted. It's pretty cool, and thatswhy you shouldn't mess with GC :D

Comment: @JonSkeet-I recompiled under Release mode and now I get False, False

Comment: @Jim, your reported result is reproducible in release build on every run on my system *IF* it is run with the debugger attached. It produces  "false, false" if run from commandline.

Comment: @Jim: Even under the debugger, still? That surprises me a bit, but I still suspect it's for the reason given in my answer, ultimately.

Comment: @JonSkeet-Building for Debug, I get True, False. Building for Release I get False, False. Interesting. If I actually step thru the program Debug or Release builds, I get the True, False output.

Comment: @Jim the reason that happens is when the debugger is attached the GC must assume that you could at any point pause the program and add a Watch Variable on any previously declared but no-longer used variable. Because of that the object will be kept alive for as long as you potentially could have a way to view it in the debugger. By running without the debugger attached the GC knows no one is going to pause the program and attach to a watch variable so it makes the object available for collection as soon as it is no longer used in the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why would lifetime of the reference be different just because of using Object Initializer?

I can't actually reproduce your problem anyway, but I *suspect* it's because this:

```
var refContainer = new RefContainer() { Target = obj };
```

is equivalent to:

```
var tmp = new RefContainer();
tmp.Target = obj;
var refContainer = tmp;
```

... so you end up with an extra reference to the object on the stack. Now when running not under the debugger, I'd *expect* the GC to notice that that stack location is never read again, and allow the object to be garbage collected - but as you're running under the debugger, the GC is more conservative, and I suspect it treats *all* stack variables as GC roots.

That's just a guess though - without being able to reproduce it anyway, it's hard to say for sure.

EDIT: Your assignments of `obj = null;` and `refContainer = null;` are pointless under non-debug mode; because the variables aren't *read* after that point anyway, the GC ignores them as GC roots.

Comment: So my intent was to determine if a WeakReference can be used to reliably determine if an object is no longer referenced and thus take some action with a containing object. Is this a good idea?

Comment: @Jim: Do you mean you want to take some action when the object *isn't* referenced any longer? Because the weak reference will lose its target...

Comment: Yes, that's what I would like to do. Essentially, when the reference count goes to zero, do something.

Comment: And to clarify, I don't exactly know what the object is just that I want to track if it is referenced anywhere.

Comment: @Jim: .NET doesn't use reference counting. It sounds like you basically want a finalizer. You could consider wrapping the object you're actually interested in within an object which has a finalizer. But I would generally discourage this sort of thing - it's brittle, hard to debug, hard to test etc.

Comment: I know :-) That's my quandary. But at least I know a little more now. Thanks.